# Does a switch LLDP MIB contain MAC addresses of connected servers?

Tags: switch, mac-address, lldp

Suppose I have a top-of-rack switch configured with LLDP. The servers in the rack are not running LLDP and therefore do not send LLDPDUs.

Does the MIB from the switch contain the MAC addresses of the servers as well as the data for other physically-connected LLDP-enabled switches?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the switch in question and the extent of its SNMP MIB-mapped functions.

Usually, a switch would provide access to its MAC table (SAT) as well as to the LLDP data is has gathered.

A server is just another MAC node for a switch, so there's no special ways to query for those.

You might be able to access LLDP data through e.g. `lldpRemSysName` and `lldpRemSysDesc`, and MAC associations through `SwitchPortFdbAddress`.

Comment: Thanks Zac.  Is the MAC table query-able with SNMP?